# Store GravityForm data in phpmyadmin (mysql)

Tags: plugins, database, mysql, plugin-gravity-forms, phpmyadmin

I'm currently developing a small portal on Wordpress for a client where users have to submit forms (created with Gravity Forms). I'd like to be able to store the data from these forms, upon submission, onto a custom database that I created on phpmyadmin. I have all the tables and structure set up, but I don't know how to feed the data through.

I know I eventually have to use the 'gform_after_submission' hook, I just don't know where to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below.  Basically after form submission we get the data `$entry` extract the values we want (in the example `$val1, $val2, $val3`) then insert that data into the custom table with `$wpdb`:

```
add_action('gform_after_submission', 'save_to_my_custom_table', 10, 2);
function save_to_my_custom_table($entry, $form)
{
  global $wpdb;

  // update for your tablename (this assumes the table lives in same database as the other wp tables)
  $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "my_custom_tablename";

  // grab from values from the entry
  $val1 = rgar( $entry, '1' );
  $val2 = rgar($entry, '2');
  $val3 = rgar($entry, '3');

  // basic insert
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `$tablename` (`val1`,`val1`, `val1`) values (%s, %s, %d)";

  // use a prepared statement
  $stmt = $wpdb->prepare($sql, $val1, $val2, $val3);

  // run the query
  $wpdb->query($stmt);
}
```

If you are wanting to connect to a database totally outside the WP app I think you might want to consider setting up an API for communicating between the two.  In that case you can still approach this very similary.  See below:

```
add_action('gform_after_submission', 'save_to_my_custom_table', 10, 2);
function save_to_my_custom_table($entry, $form)
{
  global $wpdb;

  // update for your tablename (this assumes the table lives in same database as the other wp tables)
  $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "my_custom_tablename";

  // grab from values from the entry
  $val1 = rgar( $entry, '1' );
  $val2 = rgar($entry, '2');
  $val3 = rgar($entry, '3');

  // send POST reqest to API for other database
  $endpoint = 'api.example.com';

  $body = [
      'val1'  => $val1,
      'val2'  => $val2,
      'val3'  => $val3,
  ];

  $body = wp_json_encode( $body );

  $options = [
      'body'        => $body,
      'headers'     => [
          'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
      ],
      'timeout'     => 60,
      'redirection' => 5,
      'blocking'    => true,
      'httpversion' => '1.0',
      'sslverify'   => false,
      'data_format' => 'body',
  ];

  wp_remote_post( $endpoint, $options );
}
```